# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Proof: Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, then $\mathbb{Q}$ is a domain.

(Theorem: if $R$ is a domain, then $R[x]$ is a field.)

By the theorem, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a field.

So, letting $x = \sqrt{2}$, we get $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a field. QED.

I am wondering if this is an acceptable proof? Also, I am wondering if it can be proven using facts of irreducibility? Isn't this what Galois Theory is about? I am curious, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not in fact a field, since for instance $x$ has no inverse.

The conceptual way to prove that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a field is to use the fact that $(x^2-2)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Alternately, it's not too hard to show that the inverse of any non-zero element $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is $\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2-2b^2}$.

Comment: How can we have that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a field but not $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a field? What do you mean $x$ has no inverse?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ are very different things. $\sqrt{2}$ satisfies an polynomial equation over $\mathbb{Q}$, namely $(\sqrt{2})^2-2=0$. $x$, on the other hand, is just a variable.